# Displaying MySQL data with PHP correctly?

Tags: php, mysql

Here is the current code I'm using:

```
<?php include('database.php'); ?>

<a href="http://local.mysite.com/<?php echo $service; ?>/<?php echo $city; ?>"><?php echo $city; ?> <?php echo $service; ?></a> - 
<a href="http://local.mysite.com/<?php echo $service; ?>/<?php echo $city; ?>"><?php echo $city; ?> <?php echo $service; ?></a> - 
<a href="http://local.mysite.com/<?php echo $service; ?>/<?php echo $city; ?>"><?php echo $city; ?> <?php echo $service; ?></a> - 
<a href="http://local.mysite.com/<?php echo $service; ?>/<?php echo $city; ?>"><?php echo $city; ?> <?php echo $service; ?></a> - 
<a href="http://local.mysite.com/<?php echo $service; ?>/<?php echo $city; ?>"><?php echo $city; ?> <?php echo $service; ?></a>
```

And it is showing this (with hyperlinks):

```
houston marketing services - houston marketing services - houston marketing services - houston marketing services - houston marketing services
```

The problem is that I want a different service and city shown for each of them.  What would I need to do to display 5 different links with different names?

The `$service` and `$city` are being pulled from the database.

Here's the code for the database file:

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "database_user", "password") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("database_name") or die(mysql_error()); 

$cityquery = "SELECT * FROM cities ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
$cityresult = mysql_query($cityquery);
$cityrow = mysql_fetch_row($cityresult);
$city = $cityrow[0];

$servicequery = "SELECT * FROM services ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
$serviceresult = mysql_query($servicequery);
$servicerow = mysql_fetch_row($serviceresult);
$service = $servicerow[0];
?>
```

Comment: Include code about your query and fetching

Comment: show the code that's actually pulling the data from the database. Normally you loop through the results, echoing out as you fetch the next row. I suspect you're doing this but merely assigning the row data to your vars and overwriting it each iteration, or else just pulling one row from the result set..

Comment: You have to iterate over the result set. We'll need to see your code

Comment: You need to show the relevant code. But basically, you need to loop over the database results in order to output a different result each time. http://php.net/foreach

Comment: Just updated to add the database.php code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't modifying the variables in any way during the display. You should fetch them and display rows one by one like (the database.php should return the whole response object):

```
while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
    $service = $row->service;
    $city = $row->city;
    echo "<a href=\"http://local.mysite.com/$service/$city\">$city $service</a>";
}
```

I assume you are using mysqli (since mysql is deprecated).